# How to use UIButtons in a Cell with Functions?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I created a custom cell added the actions and outlets.

I want to be able to get the cell indexpath when the cell button is pressed.

I am send data to my parse server and I need to the cell indexPath.row so when someone clicks the button the count for likes or dislikes goes up.

My Custom Cell :

```
class myTVC: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var greenUp: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var redDown: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewTVC: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var upVote: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var downVote: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func voteDownPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("downVote")


}
@IBAction func voteUpPressed(sender: UIButton) {
     print("upVote")

}


}
```

Comment: Buttons in table view cells are annoying because the cell is already a giant button. So when ever you touch a cell the cell gets priority and then when you hold it there for a little bit the cell forwards the touch to it's subviews. There is an option on table views or table view cells (i forget) that lets you forward touches to subviews first before the cell attempts to take priority. The only problem with this is that if you try to scroll and your first touch is a button in the cell then it wont scroll.

Comment: In cellForRow save the indexpath to the cell